# How to redirect after successful response from axios call

Tags: reactjs, react-router, axios

I am making a axios call and after a successful request I want to request to another webpage .SO I do like

```
getShow = event =>{
    event.preventDefault();
    const headers = {
     'Content-type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: 'Client ' + localStorage.getItem('secretKey')
    };
    axios
      .get('/api/getshow', {
        headers: headers,
        params: {
          name: this.state.sendername,
          email:this.state.senderemail
        }
      })
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res.data.name);
        return <Redirect to='/show?name=res.data.name'/>

      });
  };
```

But this is not redirecting.I also try removing the event.preventDefault(); but did not work.Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does this fit your demand?https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Hooks/usehistory

Comment: have you tried rendering the `<Redirect />` component (see the pattern described [here](https://dev.to/projectescape/programmatic-navigation-in-react-3p1l))

Comment: What's so fuss about `Redirect` component? `location.href=\`/show?name={res.data.name}\``

Comment: @keikai no using hooks have to been done inside react functions only

Comment: @Ricky Noting to do with hooks, what I said is about `push()`, you can use normal functions inside classical components, and hooks in functional components as well. https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/history

Answer (score 2):

Make a state called redirect:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { redirect: null }
}
```

Or with hooks:

```
const [ redirect, setRedirect ] = useState(null);
```

You need to set the  component in your render:

```
if (redirect) {
    return <Redirect to={redirect} />
}
```

Then in that .then of your axios just set redirect to the route you want the redirection:

```
axios
  .get('/api/getshow', {
    headers: headers,
    params: {
      name: this.state.sendername,
      email:this.state.senderemail
    }
  })
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res.data.name);
    //Hooks
    setRedirect(`/show?${res.data.name}`)
    // No hooks
    this.setState({ redirect: `/show?${res.data.name}` });

  });
```

Comment: whers is the setRedirect function?

Comment: const [ redirect, setRedirect ] = useState(null); The set redirect is the setter for redirect state. If you define the redirect state like this you can call setRedirect.

Comment: so without hooks mean I need to have a state redirect and set the component in your render and  `this.setState({ redirect: /show?${res.data.name} })`

Comment: What about the `event.preventDefault();`? should that be removed

Comment: Yes. You won't need that

Comment: Mmm when I do it refreshes the form only after submit